Monitor Docker containers on EC2 instance from Splunk Enterprise
I need to monitor the Docker containers running on my EC2 aws machine on Splunk enterprise.
I have installed Splunk and added Splunk forwarder to my EC2 machine and I am running a Docker httpd container on port 80:80. I also created a HEC token on Splunk enterprise I don't know what for.
What else should I do?

Run the forwarder in the container. Note that if you have a lot of containers that are reinstantiated, it requires having a coherent host naming strategy that includes the instance identifier.
https://hub.docker.com/r/splunk/universalforwarder
